# Angular 2: retreive data from a dynamic generated input by ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

Im generating some `input="text"` from array using `ngFor`, I need to retreive that info the user insert in those `inputs` and send by a button to a function. My code is the next one. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="well well-lg row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">
            <label class="col-md-12">Selección de Bucket</label>
            <ss-multiselect-dropdown class="col-md-12" [options]="buckets" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" (click)="selectBuckets(selectedOptions)" [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="inputs!= null">
            <p>{{inputs.name}}</p>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center" *ngFor="let input of inputs; let i = index">
                <div *ngFor="let y of input">
                  <div *ngIf="y">
                    <label>{{y.name}}</label>
                    <input #test type="text" name="" placeholder="{{y.name}}" [value]="y.originalField" [(ngModel)]="y.originalField">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-3 text-center">
            <label>Start Date: </label>
            <dp-day-picker [class.dp-material]="true" [disabled]="false" [required]="true" [(ngModel)]="fi" [config]="datePickerConfig" style="z-index:10"></dp-day-picker>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 text-center">
            <label>End Date: </label>
            <dp-day-picker [class.dp-material]="true" [disabled]="false" [required]="true" [(ngModel)]="ff" [config]="datePickerConfig"></dp-day-picker>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-xs-4 text-center">

<!-- HERE IS THE BUTTON I SHOULD SEND THE INFO FROM THE INPUTS -->
<!-- NOTE: ALSO I NEED TO SEND WITH THE START AND END DATE -->

            <button type="button" (click)="search(test)" class="btn btn-block" style="z-index:-100">Buscar</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

As you see Im generating the `inputs` from a service I have and those will be different and depends from the combinations in the `select` camp inside"`ss-multiselect-dropdown`" tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you would make this a form, where you can actually access the values. In this example, I just point out the input part of your "form", because from what I understand, that is the part where you want to access the values. But you can just wrap the code you want inside the form-tags and you're good. So, something like this:

```
<form novalidate #myForm="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let input of inputs; let i = index">
    <div *ngFor="let y of input">
      <div *ngIf="y">
        <label>{{y.name}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="y.originalField-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="y.originalField">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see I have modified the `name` in the form. To be able to use ngFor in form to actually extract all the separate values, every name has to be unique. Therefore I have added the index of the input to separate them from eachother: `name="y.originalField-{{i}}"` Otherwise you would end up with just one and the same value in all fields.

Then with the button you just pass the formvalues with `myForm.value` and do whatever you like with your values!

```
<button (click)="search(myForm.value)">Buscar</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much, It worked!! I just had to do a little change for me to work but that wasnt anything to be with my question: ```<input type="text" name="{{y.originalField}}-{{y.idBucket}}" [(ngModel)]="y.originalField">``` You going to heaven, Mr. AJT_82

Comment: Hahhaha :D You are very welcome, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

refer the reactive forms in angular2 - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html.

You can create a formgroup and create formcontrol for each input.

Comment: this is another great answer but as I see you need to code each input so It doesnt work really for me because I retreive those inputs dynamically from a database, so not always are the same inputs because them depends of each bucket I chose. Thank you for your time. Although it's good to know about reactive forms and I'll use in a future. :)