# Why I'm getting empty string from child component's input?

Tags: angular

I have one parent and one child component. In parent, I have a tab and a button. In child, only an input. When I'm trying to access the child component's input from parent, it returns an empty string even if it's filled.

**My parent component:**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {TabContent} from './tab-content.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  template: `
     <md-tab-group>
        <md-tab label="One">
           <tab-content></tab-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Two">
           <tab-content></tab-content>
        </md-tab>
     </md-tab-group>

     <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="getData()">GET DATA</button>

     <p>Data: {{ inputData }}</p>
     `
})
export class AppComponent {

  private inputData;

  @ViewChild(TabContent) content: TabContent;

  constructor() {
  }

  getData() {
    this.inputData = this.content.state.nativeElement.value; // Returns ''
  }

}
```

**My child component:**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab-content',
  template: `
    <md-input-container width="100%">
      <input #state mdInput placeholder="State">
    </md-input-container>
  `
})
export class TabContent {

  @ViewChild('state') state;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/FSpyslV2gYBYkWBctlHg?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure why the value field isn't reflecting what's actually in the input, but what is wrong with using the Forms module? That's how you really should be doing this.

Comment: Because I'm still learning Angular and I'm not yet in formular section in my course.

Comment: The reason why you are getting empty string is because you have two tabs sharing the same child component, so Angular doesn't know which input to read. I highly suggest you would wrap your child template inside a form tag, and then use "name" to differentiate the inputs from eachother. You receive an unique name from parent, e.g `tab.nbr`, that you would use in your input like `name = "{{tab.nbr}}"`

Comment: The following answer is based on `*ngFor`, but the issue is the same, to differentiate between inputs, so maybe that would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705314/angular-2-retreive-data-from-a-dynamic-generated-input-by-ngfor/41707532#41707532 Furthermore, you are using viewchild, but another option is to use `@Output()` as well. Maybe viewchild is better for you. But just to throw it out there: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent